# Run a script when either locking or unlocking Windows XP

Tags: windows, hook, locking, scripting

I have a Windows XP machine and a Linux machine running Ubuntu. I share the keyboard/mouse from the Windows machine via [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/). What I would like to do is lock/unlock the Linux machine whenever I lock/unlock the Windows machine.

So I'd like to be able to run a script of some description when Windows either locks or unlocks the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way in Windows is to [write a package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374783.aspx) (a *dll*) that subscribes to [Winlogon notification events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380544.aspx).

I don't know of any tool that provides an easy way to hook into those events, but you could make your package launch a script from some specific place if you really need your actions to be inside one.