# run command/script when lock/unlock windows station?

Tags: windows, scripting, command, locking, unlock

I have Windows 7 pro at work. My problem is I keep on forgetting to clock in/clock out (using the intranet timesheet system). Is there a way to run a script or command to automatically open the timesheet page each time I lock/unlock my station?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270629/run-a-script-when-either-locking-or-unlocking-windows-xp

Comment: that link doesn't account for new functionality in windows 7

Comment: probably belongs on superuser.com

Comment: had i known this could be done with task scheduler i woulda posted this over superuser :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, windows 7 task scheduler allows a dizzying array of new ways to schedule tasks:

One is on log on, and another is on event which could be a security event for locking the workstation.

```
Administrative Tools --> Task Scheduler
    - Create Task 
    --> Triggers Tab 
    --> New Button 
    --> Begin Task drop down box... 

etc.
```

Comment: yay it worked!

is there a way to make it so that the computer will NOT lock until i kill iexplore.exe?

tyvm!

Comment: Not that I know of... you may want to make a task that automatically writes the time to a text file when you lock the screen, and then when you unlock it then automatically bring up the timesheet AND the text file...

Comment: Nice. I wonder if its possible to pass as argument which trigger/event that started the task?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the trigger event **"on workstation unlock"**...or **"on workstation lock"**, in Windows 10 task scheduler.