# In java, how can we check that user attempted to lock windows?

Tags: java, windows

Currently i am developing a small utility in java. This utility needs to perform certain operations if the user attempts to lock the windows PC. How can i check whether a windows lock action is performed by user?

Comment: You can trigger a scheduled task on lock/unlock https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830666/run-command-script-when-lock-unlock-windows-station

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use something like [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) and call the Window APIs.

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385164/eventviewer-eventid-for-lock-and-unlock) they discuss the windows events that are responsible for telling when the user locked the computer.

Comment: What I want to do is, catch the event of window lock & display a dialog. Windows should not be locked until the "OK" on the dialog is not pressed.